# О Савонароле и занимаемой позиции

Tags: грамотная-речь

> Каждый из авторов, кто решался на описание жизненного пути этого
>   неистового проповедника, так или иначе занимает позицию – Добро или
>   Зло приносит на благоденствующие земли этот неистовый проповедник.

Что-то не так с занимаемой исследователями позицией; как исправить?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Каждый из авторов, кто решался на описание жизненного пути этого неистового проповедника, так или иначе сталкивается с дилеммой — Добро или Зло принёс он  когда-то на благословенные земли.

Answer (score 1):

**Каждый из авторов, кто решался на описание жизненного пути этого неистового проповедника, так или иначе должен был занять опредленную позицию в споре (решить для себя, определиться): Добро или Зло приносит на благоденствующие земли этот неистовый проповедник?**

"Этот неистовый проповедник" повторяется дважды(?!)

Comment: Уау! Спасибо! Я не заметила повтора! Т_Т